# Preprocessor-like substitution into a parser

Tags: c, parsing, text-parsing

I am making a parser currently which aims to be able to input data in a program.
The syntax used is greatly inspired from C.

I would enjoy to reproduct a kind of preprocessor inline substitution into it.

for example

```
#define HELLO ((variable1 + variable2 + variable3))
int variable1 = 37;
int variable2 = 82;
int variable3 = 928;
```

Thing is... I'm actually using C. I'm also using standard functions from stdio.h to parse through my files.
So... what techniques I could use to make this work correctly and efficiently?

Does the standard compilers substitute the text by re-copying the stream buffer and making the substitution there as the re-copying occurs or what? Is there more efficient techniques?

I guess we say preprocessor because it first substitutes everything until theres no preproc directives (recursive approach maybe?), and then, it starts doing the real compile job?

Excuse my lack of knowledge!

Thanks!

Comment: If you want exactly what a C preprocessor does, why don't you simply use a C preprocessor?

Comment: i prefer doing my own. less pain to adapt it to my own code. since its not a true compiler but an "on the fly" parser (i.e. convert text directives to internal data, such as arrays etc etc), i already see problems adapting it coming. i wanted to come here and ask people, free n fast answers instead of wasting time analyzing an existing code.

Comment: Consider adding a scripting language, such as Lua, to your program instead of creating yet another mini language.

Answer (score 2):

No, modern C compilers don't implement the preprocessor as a text processor, but they have the different compiler phases (preprocessing being one of them) tangled. This is particularly important for the efficiency of the compiler itself and to be able to track errors back into the original source code.

Also implementing a preprocessor by yourself is a tedious task. Think twice before you start such a project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right about preprocessors. It has the job of bringing together all files which are requires for the execution of the program to 1 file for eg. stdio.h. Then it allows the compiler to compile the program. The file you want to compile is given as argument to the compiler and the techniques used by the compiler may vary according to the os and the compiler itself

Answer (score 0):

The C preprocessor works on tokens not text. In particular, macro expansion cannot contain preprocessor directives. Other preprocessors, such as m4, work differently.